# SQL - Combining in and not in

Tags: sql, subquery

I have a SQL that shows me PRODUCTS containing 3 specific PARTS. I would like to add a condition that queries PRODUCTS containing PARTS A,B,C but not PART D:

Existing QUERY:

```
SELECT Product
FROM your_table_name
WHERE Part IN ('a', 'b', 'c')
GROUP BY Product
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT Part) = 3;
```

Subquery?

Thank you for any help!

Comment: If PART is in ('a','b','c'), then PART cannot possibly be 'D'.

Comment: Rephrased the question - Product contains part a,b,c but not d

Comment: Yes, you are free to add `and part <> 'D'` (don't use IN unnecessarily). But also note that if `count(distinct Part) = 3` then you can only have A & B & C, if part was also D then the `count(distinct Part)`  would be 4

Comment: Regarding **contains** this implies you have a parts hierarchy - but there is nothing in the question details to inform us of how this is implemented.  We need **sample data** and **expected results**. Data should be "per table" and contain all relevant columns. I suggest you read these: [Provide a `Minimal Complete Verifiable Example` (MCVE)](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)
 and [Why should I provide a MCVE](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query)

Comment: Add ´d´ to your WHERE. And use HAVING to make sure no 'd' is there. So called _conditional aggregation_, where you combine a `case` expression and an aggregate function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you use NOT EXISTS with a correlated nested query?

```
SELECT Product
FROM your_table_name
WHERE Part IN ('a', 'b', 'c') AND NOT EXISTS (
    SELECT * from your_table_name yt_inner
    WHERE yt_inner.Part = 'd' and
        yt_inner.Product = your_table_name.Product)
GROUP BY Product
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT Part) = 3;
```

Answer (score 0):

Other way.

```
AsIs:
SELECT Product
FROM your_table_name
WHERE Part IN ('a', 'b', 'c')
GROUP BY Product
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT Part) = 3;
```

```
ToBe:
SELECT a.Product
FROM (
  SELECT a.Product
    , SUM(CASE WHEN a.Part = 'a' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS A_YN
    , SUM(CASE WHEN a.Part = 'b' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS B_YN
    , SUM(CASE WHEN a.Part = 'c' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS C_YN
    , SUM(CASE WHEN a.Part = 'd' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS D_YN
  FROM your_table_name a
  GROUP BY a.Product
) a
WHERE 1=1
AND (A_YN + B_YN + C_YN) = 3
AND D_YN = 0
```

Comment: Hi JuSun, This query did not return all the values. Im not sure why. I really appreciate your effort though. Thank you!